# What IIS version does Windows Server 2008 Web Edition come with

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

Also, if an application works on IIS 7, would it be cool on the new version (if there is any)?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/10518/how-can-i-tell-what-version-of-iis-is-installed on serverfault.

Comment: @nueverest - the question you linked to is asking how do you know what version of IIS you are running.  This question is about, what version of IIS comes with a specific version of Windows Server as well as it touches on reverse compatibility of applications and IIS (hint: its pretty good)

Comment: It seems like the question should at least me moved to ServerFault.com.

Answer (score 7):

Err...even Microsoft's [marketing material](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/2008-web.aspx)(dead link) is confusing! (says both IIS 7.0 and 7.5).  However, I believe that Windows Server 2008 Web comes with IIS 7.0 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Web comes with IIS 7.5 FYI.

And yes, if you have an app working on IIS 7, it will work fine on IIS 7.5.

*Edit*:  Appears Microsoft has update their site since this was posted, leaving link up for anyone looking for information on Server and Server R2.

Comment: Marketing link is now dead.

Comment: I would try and find an updated link, but its a 5 year old answer and the product itself is nearing a decade old at this point. But I did go ahead and mark the link as dead so no one else will get an unexpected 404.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/product-information.aspx

IIS version 7.5.

My guess is if Microsoft doesn't suck, an app working in 7.0 should be fine on a newer subversion, there should be no core changes. Then again, it is Microsoft, so I can't say that for certain.

Comment: It says "Powerful tools such as Internet Information Services (IIS) version 7.5, updated Server Manager and Hyper-V platforms and Windows PowerShell version 2.0", under "What is Windows Server 2008 R2?".

Comment: 7.5 is included in R2. In vanilla 2008 it's 7.0.